# force Seq of elements to be printed on multiline in json using custom format spray json

Tags: json, scala, format, pretty-print, spray-json

```
case class Apartment(towerNumber: Int, apartmentNumber: Int)

case class Township(name: String, apartments: Seq[Apartment])
```

When printing **township** pretty json, How to display all **apartments** by single **tower number** in multiple lines

have used **ApartmentCustomJsonFormat** for **Apartment** and **private**

```
case class TownshipGroupedByTowers(name: String, apartments : Seq[Seq[Apartment]])
```

for grouping of **appartments** by **tower number**.

my attempt is here : https://scastie.scala-lang.org/moglideveloper/prWPlLkERhSapxTIZYTlow/15

actual output :-

```
{
  "apartments": [["1-1", "1-2", "1-3"], ["2-1"], ["3-1", "3-2"]],
  "name": "Orion"
}
```

expected output (apartments that belongs to single tower should be displayed in one line) :-

```
{
  "apartments": [
      ["1-1", "1-2", "1-3"],
      ["2-1"],
      ["3-1", "3-2"]
    ],
  "name": "Orion"
}
```

Comment: if you look at [JsValue prettyPrint, compactPrint and sortedPrint](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/ca03b13521bde5225bac2991ec4ab6e3c6519fe8/src/main/scala/spray/json/JsValue.scala#L30-L32) methos, all of them use [JsonPrinter](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/blob/ca03b13521bde5225bac2991ec4ab6e3c6519fe8/src/main/scala/spray/json/JsonPrinter.scala#L25) which is just a function from `JsValue` to `String`. All you have to do is create your own function to build the string you want. I don't think there is come config that you can pass as parameter to get the expected output